# DocuSign is not sending email to Signer

Tags: java, docusignapi

DocuSign is not sending email to Signer.

I have even followed below support link. I did not find any proper solution.
https://support.docusign.com/answers/00002292

while creating envelope I am using below code

```
Signer signer = new Signer();
signer.setEmail("***@gmail.com");
signer.setName("My Name");
```

and for generating URL for Iframe

```
        RecipientViewRequest returnUrl = new RecipientViewRequest();
        returnUrl.setReturnUrl("https://www.docusign.com/devcenter");
        returnUrl.setAuthenticationMethod("email");

        // recipient information must match embedded recipient info we provided
        // in step #2
        returnUrl.setEmail("***@gmail.com");
        returnUrl.setUserName("My Name");
        returnUrl.setRecipientId("1");
        returnUrl.setClientUserId("10111");
```

I am using production account with valid promoted integrator key and DocuSign Java API.

***@gmail.com user should get an email after signing process. But he/She is not getting any email. DocuSign server is sending all emails to the user whose credentials were used for creating envelope and Iframe URL.

Comment: It seems you are doing embedded signing, can you please share which emails you are expecting for the embedded signers?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `clientUserId` property for a recipient, you're making them an *embedded* recipient, and (by default) DocuSign does not send emails to embedded recipients. This behavior is by design.

**UPDATE**

It seems that there's an account configuration setting (i.e., that you can set via the DocuSign web UI) that will make DocuSign send the 'envelope complete' email to embedded recipients. See info in this support thread for more info: https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00008788.

Comment: If I am not using `clientUserId` then I can not sign on the browser after hitting generated URL.

Comment: **Send completion emails to embedded signers** is already checked. Still, the signer is not getting an email after signing.

Comment: If you login to the DocuSign web UI and look at the status of the envelope, is it "Complete"? If yes, and if the sender of the envelope is receiving the envelope complete email (but the embedded recipient is not), and if the "Send completion emails to embedded signers" checkbox is checked in the account settings, then DocuSign *should* be sending the "envelope complete" email to to the embedded recipient. If you're not seeing it in the embedded recipient's Inbox, then perhaps check the Spam/Junk Mail folder in Gmail?